# How to convert functionality under iterrows to one line in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

My data1 is as follows:

```
[
{"cut_id":1,"cut_label":"v024","cut_name":"State","value_label":"1","value":"andaman and nicobar islands"},
{"cut_id":3,"cut_label":"v024","cut_name":"State","value_label":"3","value":"arunachal pradesh"},
{"cut_id":635,"cut_label":"sdistri","cut_name":"District","value_label":"599","value":"pathanamthitta"},
{"cut_id":636,"cut_label":"sdistri","cut_name":"District","value_label":"600","value":"kollam"},
{"cut_id":637,"cut_label":"sdistri","cut_name":"District","value_label":"601","value":"thiruvananthapuram"}
]
```

The output I want is as follows:

```
[
{"value_label":"S1","value":"andaman and nicobar islands"},
{"value_label":"S3","value":"arunachal pradesh"},
{"value_label":"D599","value":"pathanamthitta"},
{"value_label":"D600","value":"kollam"},
{"value_label":"D601","value":"thiruvananthapuram"}
]
```

My intention is rename the value label by appending the number with a character either 'S' or 'D' depending on whether it is a state or district.

This is my code:

```
for _, r in data[
        (data['cut_name'] == 'State') | (data['cut_name'] == 'District')][
            ['cut_name', 'value', 'value_label']
    ].iterrows():
    cuts_data[r.cut_name[0]+r.value_label] = r.value
```

I got the result as expected, but is there a way to do this in one line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `str` with indexing for get first value of `cut_name` and if necessary filter it by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
mask = data['cut_name'].isin(['State','District'])
data.loc[mask, 'value_label'] = data['cut_name'].str[0] + data['value_label'].astype(str)
```

If only `State` or `District` possible values:

```
data['value_label'] = data['cut_name'].str[0] + data['value_label'].astype(str)
```

For improve performance is possible use list comprehension (working nice is non missing values):

```
data['value_label'] = [c[0] + str(v) for c, v in zip(data['cut_name'], data['value_label'])]
```

If need new DataFrame with filtered columns:

```
new_df = data[['value','value_label']]
```

Comment: Thanks, what about lambda and apply??

Comment: @virupaksha - I think it is possible by `data['value_label'] =  data['cut_name'].apply(lambda x: x[0]) + data['value_label'].astype(str)` - what is reason for use it?

Comment: @virupaksha - some problem?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there definitely is:

```
df.loc[df['cut_name'].isin(['State', 'District']), 'value_label'] = np.where(df['cut_name'] == 'State', 'S' + df['value_label'], 'D' + df['value_label'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this if you want to use `apply` and `lambda`

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
{"cut_id":1,"cut_label":"v024","cut_name":"State","value_label":"1","value":"andaman and nicobar islands"},
{"cut_id":3,"cut_label":"v024","cut_name":"State","value_label":"3","value":"arunachal pradesh"},
{"cut_id":635,"cut_label":"sdistri","cut_name":"District","value_label":"599","value":"pathanamthitta"},
{"cut_id":636,"cut_label":"sdistri","cut_name":"District","value_label":"600","value":"kollam"},
{"cut_id":637,"cut_label":"sdistri","cut_name":"District","value_label":"601","value":"thiruvananthapuram"}
])

n_df = pd.DataFrame()

n_df['value'] = df['value']
n_df['value_label'] = df.apply(lambda x : x['cut_name'][0] + x['value_label'], axis=1)

n_df.T.to_dict().values()

#Output

[{'value': 'andaman and nicobar islands', 'value_label': 'S1'}, {'value': 'arunachal pradesh', 'value_label': 'S3'}, {'value': 'pathanamthitta', 'value_label': 'D599'}, {'value': 'kollam', 'value_label': 'D600'}, {'value': 'thiruvananthapuram', 'value_label': 'D601'}]
```